# documents are not being added to solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using the [SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet) library to interface with solr from .net.  I had to make some changes to the solarconfig.xml file to get solr to use my schema.xml file instead of the managed schema.  Eventually it all loaded in the dashboard area and I thought things were good.  Then I tried to add some documents to the index using the following.

```
var itemsToAdd = new List<FindDocument>()
{
    new FindDocument()
    {
        Id = "a1",
        DocumentType = "Agency",
        Email = "test@test.com"
    },
    new FindDocument()
    {
        Id = "a2",
        DocumentType = "Agency",
        Email = "test2@test.com"
    },
    new FindDocument()
    {
        Id = "r1",
        DocumentType = "Recruiter",
        Email = "recruiter@test.com"
    }
};

var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<FindDocument>>();
solr.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
solr.Commit();
```

When I then went into the solr dashboard, selected my core and tried to query it it showed 0 documents.  I manually tried to add a document through the dashboard's Documents tab.  It returns a success message but again, querying returns 0 documents.  Here's what I'm seeing in the log.

The solrnet addition log -

```
2017-11-07 18:46:59.182 INFO  (qtp7980742-42) [   x:TenixFind] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessor [TenixFind] webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} {add=[a1 (1583434085624184832), a2 (1583434085624184833), r1 (1583434085624184834)]} 0 50
2017-11-07 18:46:59.296 INFO  (qtp7980742-41) [   x:TenixFind] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessor [TenixFind] webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} {commit=} 0 0
2017-11-07 18:47:38.823 INFO  (qtp7980742-42) [   x:TenixFind] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessor [TenixFind] webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} {add=[a1 (1583434127189737472), a2 (1583434127189737473), r1 (1583434127190786048)]} 0 44
2017-11-07 18:47:38.922 INFO  (qtp7980742-41) [   x:TenixFind] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessor [TenixFind] webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} {commit=} 0 0
```

And then the manual dashboard add.

```
2017-11-07 18:57:21.176 INFO  (qtp7980742-46) [   x:TenixFind] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessor [TenixFind] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json} {add=[abc123 (1583434737832165376)]} 0 0
```

I am not getting any errors so I'm not sure why the documents aren't being saved.  Due to the restrictions of where this will be running, I'm having to run an older version of solr - 5.3.0.

Also, as a bit of background, when solr was originally set up to use the managed schema I was able to add documents.  However it wouldn't use my custom field types and dynamic fields since it wasn't reading the schema.xml file.  I tried to modify the managed schema file with these custom fields/types and although they worked I was told by a coworker that in the production environment I'd have to get solr to use the schema.xml file instead of the managed schema due to how it's running.

Edit:

I found the problem.  When updating the solrconfig.xml file to use the schema.xml instead of managed-schema file you also have to remove the following from the solrconfig.

```
<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
  </lst>
</processor>
```

However it was directly followed by another line which I accidentally removed.

```
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
```

Once I put that back in it started saving documents.

Comment: How are you querying? Have you tried searching with just the query `*:*` through the API endpoint? (`/collection/select?q=*:*`)

Comment: In the dashboard area I go to Query and use q=*:* and then Execute Query.